# Measure the distance between points automatically

Tags: qgis, point, distance, measurements

How can I measure the distance between points referring to the same element in an automated way? In fact I've imported in QGIS buildings downloaded from two different sources and obviously they are not placed exactly in the same position.

Comment: create a line using points that have the same ID and measure the lengths of the lines?